# Automatically define macros in LyX documents

Tags: latex, lyx

I'm using LyX all the time and over the last 2 years I've accumulated some very handy macros for my lecture notes. As it is today, every time I start a new document, I copy and paste the macros from one of my other documents. Is it possible, somehow, to automatically load macros for all files?

Comment: Maybe you can make your own package `mypack.sty` or class files `myarticle.cls` I can do that only in actual directory, but it is possible to add your files to LaTeX's base and call them as standard packages and classes. Ant that I do not know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define your macros in the preamble (Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble) then press the "save as document defaults" button.